# Transportation and action

Tags: prepositions, phrase-request

In Russian when we are walking to a bus stop or a tram station we can say, **"I am going on (Russian "на") the bus/tram"** which would mean - **" I am going to the bus stop/tram station and am going to travel somewhere by bus/tram"** not just stand there or be there for no reason.

What do you say in that case in English when you mean **the actions of arriving at a bus stop/tram station and boarding the transport in order to travel somewhere**?

Comment: I'm going by bus.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang No, that's not what I mean. It means if you are already travelling aboard the bus.

Comment: I will be going by bus? Although "I'm going by bus" does not have to mean you are already on the bus. "How are you getting there? How will you be getting there? I'm going by bus. I'll be going by bus." Or had I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang You have misunderstood me. Imagine this, you are walking to bus stop to take a bus to go somewhere when your friend calls you and ask, *"Hi. What are you doing?"*. What do you say? In Russian it is **"Я иду на автобус"**... in English it would sound like you are *assaulting the bus*, however, it means something like **"I'm approaching the bus stop and I'm going to board a bus now"**.

Comment: Oh, got it. "I'm taking the bus" or "I'm getting on a bus" or "I'm going to take the bus." I assume we are allowing the listener to ask a follow-up question, such as, "Oh, where you going?" or "Oh, why are you doing that?," etc.?

Comment: And out of curiosity, why does it sound like we'd be "assaulting" the bus in English? Is it an idiom in Russian?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang What about **"I'm going to the bus"** or **"I'm going on the bus"**?

Comment: "I'm going to the bus" would not necessarily imply that we are getting on. And "I'm going on the bus" is not idiomatic. "I'm getting on the bus" would probably be the better choice.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang No, but the buses are always overfilled with people here so you surely assault them.

Comment: And what about the difference between **"Take a bus"** and **"Catch a bus"**? That's an extra...

Comment: Heh, I see. I find the subway here to be more crowded so actually, I prefer the bus myself :D. With less assaulting and more taking.

Comment: "Catch" would be a more visual word for me and would almost imply for me that I'm in a bit of a hurry to "take" that bus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English one might say

> I'm taking a bus/train/plane.
>   I'm catching a bus/train/plane.

The reason your sentence's meaning works in Russian is because its implied.

In Russian there are different verbs for *walking* (идти) and *riding* (ездить), also **на автобусе** literally means "*on the bus*" but can be understood to mean "*by bus*" so there is an implied linguistic split in your sentence which allows for the understanding of *walking* then *riding*.

> catch a bus to...
>   take a bus to...

means you are going to get on bus and going somewhere, but you don't know how you got to the bus, unless there is further context.